# Where are the Eight Worldly Winds and how to deal with them described?

Tags: philosophy

To refresh your memory, the Eight Worldly Winds are:

1. Pleasure
2. Pain
3. Praise
4. Blame
5. Gain
6. Loss
7. Fame
8. Ill-repute

Comment: I am also curious to know why they are called 'winds'.  Term in original language?

Comment: The only source I found which indicates the reason why it's called 'winds' is Milinda Pañha pg.354 where they are called *aṭṭhalokadhammavātehi*, "by winds
of the eight worldly conditions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mentioned in both the [Lokavipatti Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.006.than.html) in the Pali Canon, and in verse 29 of Nagarjuna's "[Letter to a Friend](http://www.berzinarchives.com/web/en/archives/sutra/level6_study_major_texts/suhrllekha_letter_friend_nagarjuna/letter_friend.html)."

The short answer on how to deal with them is: see them for what they are. Transient sources of suffering.